# Ilovepdf Api saing file does not exists

Tags: php, pdf

I have a code to merge two pdfs with Ilovepdf api, one of my pdf is save on my server and I can access it with the url, but when I put the url to the IlovePdf merged, it say it doesn't exist.

My code:

```
  $ilovepdf = new Ilovepdf($_ENV['ILOVEPDF_PUBLIC'], $_ENV['ILOVEPDF_SECRET']);
    // Create a new task
    $myTaskMerge = $ilovepdf->newTask('merge');
    // Add files to task for upload
    $urlPagadoria = $_SESSION['urlPagadoria'];
    $arq = $urlPagadoria . '/uploads/Pagamentos/' . $arquivo;
    $file1 = $myTaskMerge->addFile($arq);
    $arq2 = $urlPagadoria . '/Arquivo.pdf';
    $file2 = $myTaskMerge->addFile($arq2);
    // Execute the task
    $myTaskMerge->execute();
    // Download the package files
    $myTaskMerge->download();
```

The error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: File https://myurl.com/Arquivo.pdf does not exists in /home/cloudpanel/htdocs/myurl.com/Pagadoria/vendor/ilovepdf/ilovepdf-php/src/Task.php:191
```

If I try to access the https://myurl.com/Arquivo.pdf it downloads the file

Comment: I would recommend using the local file path instead of the Url when trying to merge the PDFs. Ilovepdf is most likely just trying to use the local file functions and not anything that can use http

Comment: Put on a temp folder on my local and it's working, thank you!